# Unspecified run time error while executing vba script

Tags: excel, oracle, vba

I am new to vba and I am using vba script to connect to database from excel and get the records. I have written the following script for that.I am getting a run time error '-2147467259(80004005)':Unspecified error. 
How to resolve this error. See the error screen shot.

```
 Sub Ora_Connection()
        Dim con As ADODB.Connection
        Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
        Dim query As String

        Set con = New ADODB.Connection
        Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
        '---  Replace below highlighted names with the corresponding values
        strCon = "Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle}; " & _
        "CONNECTSTRING=(DESCRIPTION=" & _
        "(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)" & _
        "(HOST=host_name)(PORT=1521))" & _
        "(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=service_name))); uid=id; pwd=pw;"
        '---  Open the above connection string.
        con.Open (strCon)
        '---  Now connection is open and you can use queries to execute them.
        '---  It will be open till you close the connection
        query = "select * from security.forms"
        Set rs = con.Execute(query)

        For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
            Sheet1.Cells(1, i + 1).Value = rs.Fields(i).Value
        Next



        con.Close
        End Sub
```

Error screen shot:
[image: Error Message]

Comment: What happens when you click debug? Which line is highlighted?

Comment: Set rs = con.Execute(query)

Comment: Have you tested your query `select * from security.forms` work on a DB client?

Comment: yes, When I execute this query in toad it is givng the records.

Comment: Are you sure the values in the connection string are correct? Looking at it you've got `SERVICE_NANE=service_name` along with `uid=id` and `pwd=pw`

Comment: The connection string which I gave in my code(Not which I posted) is correct only.Because if I just open the connection without doing any query then connect get open without any error.

Comment: Ok just wanted to check!

Answer (score 0):

Had you tried to use the open method of your RecordSet instance? Maybe it will give you another error that will be more helpful.

```
Dim connection As New ADODB.connection
Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim query As String

connection.ConnectionString = CONNECTION_STRING
connection.Open

rst.Open query, connection, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic

do while not rst.EOF
   rst.MoveNext
loop

connection.Close
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem and it was tough to find an answer since most posts on this issue are unanswered.

I solved it by using another Oracle driver. Instead of *Microsoft ODBC for Oracle* try using the *Oracle in OraClient11g_home1* driver. Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

Please add the reference 'Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library'

[image]

Comment: Pretty sure that if ADO isn't referenced, excel will throw a `User-Defined type not defined` error not an unspecified error.

Comment: I have already added that ADO reference. Still Getting the same error.